# How to remove web/ from url (symfony)

Tags: url, symfony

I am using symfony 3. I want to remove web/ from **url** like this.

localhost/symfony/web/
to
localhost/symfony/

but I want all my asset (css, js etc) in web folder.

Like other frameworks (codeigniter, cakephp), we access main controller from **root** not **web** folder

Anybody can help

Comment: Could you provide your webserver/vhost config?

Comment: Point your domain to `web/` directory.

Comment: thank for solution. If I use share hosting then how abc.com/web/ to abc.com/

Answer (score 3):

I am using this htaccess in the root directory. It could help you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to change the `DocumentRoot` path in your Virtual Host configuration in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...
   DocumentRoot /path/to/project/web
</VirtualHost>
```

This way Apache will point to your `web/` folder instead of your project root folder and will avoid having the `/web/` in your URL.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by changing the DocumentRoot path in your Virtual Host configuration in Apache.

## Step-1

Open `D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and put below code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias www.mysite.dev
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/symfony_demo/web"
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/symfony_demo/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/mysite_error.log"
    ##CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And save this file

## Step-2

Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and put below code

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.dev
```

and save

## Step-3

Restart Apache and hit "mysite.dev" in browser